# Total commander - how to open directory in other file browser and how to sync to the same folder

Tags: total-commander

I started using Total commander because its old school and a lot of programmers I've seen work with it. I like it but I want to learn more tricks and shortcuts.

Now I want to open a directory I selected in the right file browser in the left file browser. Also sometimes I need to checkout two directory's who are in the same parent directory. When I have found and selected the parent directory how do I open The same directory in the other file browser area.

I tried to search Google for this but I only find shortcuts to open directory's in new tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> will do this.

Let's say your cursor is in the left pane, then:

- if the cursor is on sub-directory then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> will open this sub-directory in the right pane.
- if the cursor is anywhere else, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> will open the same directory in the right pane

Comment: OK thanks very handy, I could not find this on their website.